# What is the decimal equivalent of the 32-bit IEEE floating point value CC4C0000?

Tags: hex, decimal, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

First thing I do is to convert it into binary and so I get

CC4C0000 = 1100 1100 0100 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000

Now I know the number is negative because the sign bit (the first bit in the binary representation is 1).

And the exponent is the next 8 bits which is 10011000 which is equal to 2^7 + 2^4 + 2^3 = 128 + 16 + 8 = 152

Now the fractional part is the remaining 23 bits 100 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000.

Now here is my question , what is the true exponent ?

It should be 152-127 = 25 right ?

The fractional part is .100 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000

And after reinserting the leading one we have 1.100 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000.

Now I know that .100 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 is equal to 0.59375

And so the final answer should be -1.59375 x 2^25.

But why it is not the correct answer.

When I put cc4c0000 in this url

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

The answer is different , where is my error if any ?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your train of thought is correct and you did not make any mistakes.

-1.59375 * 2^25 = -53477376

Which is exactly the answer the webapp you linked gives me. Double check that you didn't make any silly errors during the final multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of assumptions here:

- Bytes are in "Network" order (i.e. more significant bytes first)
- Format is IEEE 754 (but in fairness I don't know what other IEEE format it could be ..)

Using Python I can use `unhexlify` command to convert your hex-string data as a string of bytes and then `struct.unpack` to read it in as IEEE 754 ...

```
struct.unpack('!f', unhexlify('CC4C0000'))
(-53477376.0,)
```

I can't say for sure if this is the "correct answer" for you given assumptions, but it should give you a tool with which to determine it.

The documentation for python `struct` module is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters